# GPL with Classpath Exception License

Tags: gpl, license

for example, File A.java is distributed under GPL with Classpath Exception License..
And I develop software C. There is a B.java file in C. B.java imports A(not A.jar, but A.java) and call function of A.java

In this case, should I release code of B.java or all source code of software C?
Or I wander that I need not release code of B and C in public.

Answer (score 2):

If the file B.java uses the A.java from your development environment and that can not be switched to another version of A at runtime, then the Classpath Exception to the GPL license can never trigger. As a result, software C, which contains B.java, must comply with the GPL terms and be released itself under a GPL-compatible open-source license.