# GPL with Classpath Exception License

Tags: licensing

for example, File A.java is distributed under GPL with Classpath Exception License.. And I develop software C. There is a B.java file in C. B.java imports A(not A.jar, but A.java) and call function of A.java

In this case, should I release code of B.java or all source code of software C? Or I wander that I need not release code of B and C in public.

Comment: The license of B is not important because I just want to know B.java or software C is affected by GPL of A .java

Comment: Questions about the effect of open source licenses, as with other legal documents, should be on topic here. This should not be closed for that reason.

Comment: I believe this is the same question as https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/8527/gpl-with-classpath-exception-license, migrated from Law.SE. if that's right, please feel free to delete this duplicate. (I'll verify later if you don't get a chance to.)